# Microsoft Graph API notification delivery

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

We create an application that receives notifications that there was a call. For this we create a subscription (communications / callRecords) to receive notification.

My question is, if there are errors when renewing the subscription, then all the notifications that occurred when the subscription was inactive will be lost?

Also I found that we can use Azure Event Hub ([Get change notifications delivered in different ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery)) to send notifications to the hub and then read data from it, but for this case we need to keep subscription up-to-date?

Is there a way to guarantee receiving notifications?